# how to show progress bar of upload in the notification tray flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am working a app that require uploading large file. i dont want to show progress in the application, i want to show it in the notification tray, and when complete it show successful in the notification tray, while uploading to firebase Firestore...

The function for uploading..

```
Future<bool> imageBannerPick(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: source);
  if (pickedFile == null) {
    return false;
  }
  File image = File(pickedFile.path);

  String uploadString = await uploadingFile(uploadFile: image);
  //storing the string to your profile
  await firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser?.uid).update({
    'backBannerPicture': uploadString,
  });
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Future<void> showNotificationWithProgress() async {
    const int maxProgress = 100;

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
    AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel_id',
        'channel_name',
        'channel_description',
        importance: Importance.high,
        priority: Priority.high,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        playSound: true,
        onlyAlertOnce: true,
        showProgress: true, // set this to true to show progress bar
        maxProgress: maxProgress,
        progress: 0, // set the initial progress to 0
);

    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        'Uploading...',
        'Uploading file',
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x',
);

    // update the progress periodically
    for (int progress = 0; progress <= maxProgress; progress += 10) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            'Uploading...',
            'Uploading file',
            platformChannelSpecifics.copyWith(progress: progress),
        payload: 'item x',
    );
    }

    // hide the progress bar and show a completed notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        'Upload complete',
        'File uploaded successfully',
        platformChannelSpecifics.copyWith(progress: null),
    payload: 'item x',
);
}
```

Comment: this is using local notification rigth ?

Comment: also, base on the code in the question how will you integrate with it. i will also like you to explain with it

Answer (score 0):

```
  static Future<void> showProgressNotification(
      int progress, int maxProgress) async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
          AndroidNotificationDetails('progress channel', 'progress channel',
              channelShowBadge: false,
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              onlyAlertOnce: true,
              showProgress: true,
              maxProgress: maxProgress,
              progress: progress);
      final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
          0, 'Upload ', 'image uploaded', platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');
    });
  }

  static cancelnotifivcation() async {
    await _notificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
  }
```

Comment: are you using, Local notification ?